# I am using Python3 and I want to use RabbitMQ

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq

I am using Python3 and I want to use RabbitMQ. I already tried to use Pika, and txAMQP but they do not support Python 3. Have anybody an idea how I can use RabbitMQ.

Comment: This is incorrect, `py-amqplib` *does* support Python 3 [according to their Google Code page](https://code.google.com/p/py-amqplib/): *"Also features [...] Python 3.x compatibility (via 2to3 being invoked automatically by setup.py) [...]"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html

So sadly you're not going to be able to use pika for python 3.x work since it's only supported for 2.x. There was a github repository which talks about doing preliminary work on pika 3.x support but that was closed 2 years ago.

The good news is that you can still use py-amqplib

http://code.google.com/p/py-amqplib/

The bad news is that I can't offer much help beyond pointing you in the right direction. I've only used pika while working with rabbitmq.

Comment: For those looking now, pika just got python 3 support: http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/version_history.html#b1-2015-07-10

Answer (score 8):

Check this page https://github.com/hollobon/pika-python3
May be it can help you.

Comment: This is now updated to version 0.9.13. It works well for us with Python 3.2.

Comment: pip install python3-pika works like a charm under Python 3.3.5.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the performance or features of librabbitmq rather than a pure-Python library, I wrote https://github.com/jbg/rabbit which, although being fairly rudimentary, does allow you to use the librabbitmq C library on Python 3.

EDIT 18 months later: I renamed the package to rabbitmq due to it conflicting with an existing PyPI package, and it's now on PyPI, so you can just `pip install rabbitmq`.

Answer (score 0):

For my project I have used Celery, a very good library and it works very good with python3!!!

here is a link whit the information.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery/

Comment: Celery is indeed very good, but you will still need to choose an AMQP library.